# Play Store app only for Nexus 5/5x emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play

When creating a virtual device in Android studio, there is a possibility to choose configuration which has integrated Play Store app. In my case, that is only possible when creating a Nexus 5X or Nexus 5 device.

If you take a look at the screenshot, the Play Store icon appears only next to these two devices. And what about the other configurations? Can we create them with Play Store app as well or that's currently not possible?

[image: emulator.png]

I have latest Android Studio (3.0.1) and Android Emulator (ver. 27.0.3).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I have found on Android Developer website:

> Notice that only some hardware profiles are indicated to include Play Store. This indicates that these profiles are fully CTS compliant and may use system images that include the Play Store app.
>
> Notice that some system images are labeled with Google APIs, which means it includes access to Google Play services. Other system images are labeled with Google Play, which means it includes the Google Play Store app and access to Google Play services.

[Readmore](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html)

Comment: Didn't notice that before, thank you very much Riajul!

Comment: I have also wondered about this and never noticed mention of it in the documentation.  If anyone is interested it can be found here -->https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html

The question is...what's taking so long to get the other hardware profiles complaint?  Most importantly, and at the very least, an AndroidTV emulator that's CTS compliant to aid with testing an In-App Billing implementation on the AndroidTV platform.